# Using jQuery in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, jquery, javafx

I have a conceptual question - is it possible to use jQuery of any version in JavaFX application (I mean, JS scripting)?

And is it needed to use some middleware library - maybe native JS is more suitable?

Comment: Sample combining [JavaFX with jQuery commands issued against pages loaded in a WebView](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3077942).  Another sample for a [jQueryUI based date picker embedded in a JavaFX application](http://jewelsea.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/jqueryui-based-datepicker-for-javafx/). Perhaps the links are helpful to you, but I can't tell from your question if that is exactly what you are asking about as the question is quite unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know you can't because JavaFX get compiled to Java bytecode, even if you can theme it with CSS, don't get confused JavaFX is not a webpage and it doesn't has a DOM.

Even though you can interact with javascript in the webpage in which is embedded as you can see [Java FX and Javascript Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_javascript.htm)